# Bootstrap search bar in navbar with transition

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've got two issues:

1. I'm adding a search bar in my bootstrap code, and I want it to expand like GitHub's, but the text right next to it is not expanding alongside.
2. When the dropdown appears instead of the navbar, the transition still takes effect and I'm not sure how to prevent the transition.

```css
#searchbar-top-nav:focus {
  width: 450px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="mb-1 shadow-sm">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BRAND</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul id="navbar-collapse-ul" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active-search-blue">
              <input id="searchbar-top-nav" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="sign-up-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="log-in-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/login/?next=/">Sign In</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I tried some CSS selectors like this:

```
#searchbar-top-nav:not(.collapsed):focus {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/acwpython/gd8t04nh/
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

First add margin to search bar to align correctly add bootstrap class `mt-lg-0 mt-md-2` to search bar `li`.that is

```
<li class="nav-item active-search-blue mt-lg-0 mt-2">
```

also add transitions

```
.navbar-collapse{
  transition: 0s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

```css
#searchbar-top-nav:focus {
  width: 450px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  float: left;
}
.navbar-collapse{
  transition: 0s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="mb-1 shadow-sm">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BRAND</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul id="navbar-collapse-ul" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active-search-blue mt-lg-0 mt-2">
              <input id="searchbar-top-nav" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="sign-up-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="log-in-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/login/?next=/">Sign In</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Are you want like this?

Comment: Please re-read the question. I don't think anything really changed functionality wise...

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just add min-width: 100%; to your .form-control class and
That's it.

.form-control{min-width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-control{min-width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="mb-1 shadow-sm">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BRAND</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul id="navbar-collapse-ul" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active-search-blue">
              <input id="searchbar-top-nav" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="sign-up-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">

              <a id="log-in-link" class="nav-link" href="/accounts/login/?next=/">Sign In</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```